# Visual Studio Installer : How to remove keys in the registry

Tags: installation, registry

I have an installer that is supposed to set up a menu item in the context menu of Excel add-ins (.xla, .xlam).

Manually, I know how to modify the registry to get that item which launches my .exe on the selected file. The key has to be something like :

*HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Excel.Addin\shell\Name of my program\command*

With *command* containing one string of key "(Default)" and value "my exe.exe %1".

By using the below wizard in Visual Studio installer (to get the location of my .exe which the user can choose to put where he prefers), I manage to place this command just where needed.

[image]

Problem is that it also creates another "(Default)" just before mine in the "command" key when I look at the registry. The result is of course that my "Default" is not considered...

[image]

Comment: The installer stuff that comes with Visual Studio is absolute garbage.  Forget that it exists and use a real installer tool - there are plenty of good ones out there.  Most teams at Microsoft use WiX which is open source (http://wix.sourceforge.net/) or you can buy something like InstallShield that will give you a nice IDE.

Comment: Don't create a key named `(Default)`. Just create one without a name, but with a value. It will replace the existing default one. (The default key is one that is used if no specific key is used, eg. `""` - that's why yours isn't the same. Yours is named `(Default)`, and the one that was already there is `the one used if nothing is specified`, which is different.)

Comment: That was it, thanks. Could you put your comment as solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Ken White's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283798/visual-studio-installer-how-to-remove-keys-in-the-registry#comment11706301_9283798):

> Don't create a key named (Default). Just create one without a name,
>   but with a value. It will replace the existing default one. (The
>   default key is one that is used if no specific key is used, eg. "" -
>   that's why yours isn't the same. Yours is named (Default), and the one
>   that was already there is the one used if nothing is specified, which
>   is different.)